# How to change the onclick function inside an onclick function Javascript html

Tags: javascript, html

```
<img src="Imagens/R5.jpg" id="Image1" class="P1" value="R5" style="width:164px;height:164px;margin: 0 auto;" onclick="pergunta1(this)" >
<img src="Imagens/R2.jpg" id="Image2" class="P1" value="R2" style="width:163px;height:163px;margin: 0 auto;" onclick="pergunta1(this)" >
<img src="Imagens/R8.jpg" id="Image3" class="P1" value="R8" style="width:163px;height:163px;margin: 0 auto;" onclick="pergunta1(this)" >
```

Im trying to change the onclick function of my image hoder

```
function pergunta1(element){
        var res="";
    if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R5"){
        res= "N1_5"
    }
    else if (element.getAttribute("value") == "R2"){
        res="N1_2"
    }
    else{
        res ="N1_8"
    }
    document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML =res;
    document.getElementById('Image1').src='Imagens/R7.jpg'
    document.getElementById('Image2').src='Imagens/R1.jpg'
    document.getElementById('Image3').src='Imagens/R6.jpg'
    document.getElementById('Image1').value='R7'
    document.getElementById('Image2').value='R1'
    document.getElementById('Image3').value='R6'
    document.getElementById('Image1').onclick = pergunta2(this);
    document.getElementById('Image2').onclick = "pergunta2(this)";
    document.getElementById( 'Image3' ).setAttribute( "onClick", "javascript: pergunta2(this);" );

}
```

I have done some research and tried 3 diferent ways but none of them seem to work

Comment: Could you explain what you are trying to do?

Comment: This is a duplicated question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50945223/how-do-i-return-the-value-of-the-image-in-html-javascript

Comment: i managed to find an answer i used JQuery i had tried it before but for some reason it didnt worked

this is the code i used
$("#Image1").attr('onclick', 'pergunta2(this)');

Answer (score 0):

Try;

```
document.getElementById('Image1').removeEventListener('click', pergunta1).addEventListener('click', pergunta2)
```